# tableViewSelectionDidChange não funciona no Xcode 8

Tags: osx

Após atualizar para o macOS Sierra, e consequentemente para o Xcode 8, a função `tableViewSelectionDidChange` não funciona mais. Penso que o meu código esteja correto.

```
func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {

        if let selectedRow = (notification.object as AnyObject).selectedRow {
            if ( selectedRow > -1 ) {
                selectedItem = data[selectedRow]
                if let nome = selectedItem?.value(forKey: "nome") as? String {
                    nomeField.stringValue = nome
                } else {
                    blankOutField(nomeField)
                }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let appDelegate = NSApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate
        managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        fetchDataAndRefreshTable()
    }

    func fetchDataAndRefreshTable() {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> (entityName: "CadastroPacientes")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nome", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare(_:)))
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        do {
            data = try managedContext!.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
        } catch {
            Swift.print(error)
        }
    }
```

Não consigo achar a solução pois parece que a linha não é selecionada, nada acontece quando clico no linha na `TableView`.

o Programa está usando Core Data, antes tudo funcionava perfeitamente.

Comment: Problema resolvido. Bastou trocar o operador binário para ( selectedItem >= -1 ) e tudo funcionou corretamente.